# Change link to blog post from text to an image link

Tags: image, hyperlink, jekyll, blogs

I'm new to jekyll and coding, I was hoping someone could kindly help me.

I am creating a website that has two separate blogs on it. One blog has the typical list of blog posts to click on. For the second blog I would like to have a page of photos that are links to a blog post written  based on that image.

My question is, how can I change the code to have the "photo blog" page display the images rather than a list of links.

Here is a link to my repository: https://github.com/vasilisa-the-beautiful/vasilisa
The website: https://beautifully-bipolar.com/

Also, you'll notice that when you click the photo-blog link the layout shifts. I've been trying to fix that for a week now. Please help before I go crazy :'D

Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Hello, I created a pull request to give you an example on how to achieve what you requested in your post.  https://github.com/vasilisa-the-beautiful/vasilisa/pull/6

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I haven't been online lately- sorry for the late response. I really appreciate your help!!